# didn’t look ashamed and <flinch away> or <didn’t flinch> from his gaze?

Tags: grammar

Should I use the base form of the verb “**flinch**” after "**and**", or should I use the past tense?

> a. When she stared back at him, he didn’t look ashamed and **flinch away** from his gaze.
>
> b. When she stared back at him, he didn’t look ashamed and **didn’t flinch** away from his gaze.

Here's what I think: I believe they are both correct. The “**didn’t**” applies both to “**feel ashamed**” and to “**flinch away**”.

Comment: I prefer _or_ instead of _and_ in sentence (a).

Comment: I agree with J.R. that "or" sounds better than "and", because the sentence is generally framed as a negative, "she neither A nor B" => "She didn't do A or B".  Otherwise the choice of whether to repeat the "didn't" is entirely personal style.

Comment: Hi, there, J.R. and Andrew: I understand where you guys are coming from and I agree with you, but don’t you think that in (a) the “didn’t” applies both to “feel ashamed” and to “flinch away”? I mean If I wrote the sentence in the past, it would be like this: [she felt ashamed and flinched away from her gaze.]

Comment: Whatever you decide, except it's **her gaze** not his. She was staring at him and he didn't flinch. Usually, one would not add gaze here. "away from her gaze". Or: He didn't avert his eyes from her gaze. You have some semantic issues there.

Comment: Lambie: Yes, you are right that it should be "her gaze", but I can easily change it to [When she stared back at him, he didn’t look ashamed and flinch his gaze away from her.]

Comment: Hi, there, Lambie: You said I can’t use "flinch" in this context, Here’s an example: I flinched away from his gaze, rubbing my newly bruised bicep muscle. 
https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=inT8W52dGcTe0wLpjImQAQ&q=%22+I+flinched+away+from+his+gaze%22&oq=%22+I+flinched+away+from+his+gaze%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299k1.9411.11357.0.11784.5.5.0.0.0.0.101.349.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.290....0.bii1sw2x84M

Comment: There’s another option: I can change “ flinch his gaze away” to “drop his gaze.”

Comment: And here's another example for ''to flinch one's gaze from someone" She flinched her gaze away, then forced herself to return her regard to the horrific sight. https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=kXP8W7-5JoTa8APp3bbIDQ&q=%22she+flinched+her+gaze+away+%22&oq=%22she+flinched+her+gaze+away+%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...624926.630811.0.631618.10.9.1.0.0.0.197.919.6j3.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.IblYXRgm59g

Comment: @GrammarBoy The link you provided still show someone flinching away from *someone else's* gaze. A person can flinch away from someone else's gaze (move away from the other person's gaze), or they can flinch their own gaze away (move their own gaze somewhere else), but a person cannot flinch away *from their own* gaze, because a person is not *in* their own gaze (unless they are looking in a mirror).

Comment: Generally, one flinches ***at*** something. Not away from something....to flinch at his gaze=means=when he looks at me, I flinch.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you both are correct. In the first sentence, I can just about see the "didn't" applying to both the "ashamed" and "flinch away" part.

Your second sentence sounds clearer to me though:

> When she stared back at him, he didn’t look ashamed and **didn’t** flinch
>   away from his gaze.

Or:

> When she stared back at him, he didn’t look ashamed **or** flinch
>   away from his gaze.

Comment: You are repeating the mistakes made by the OP.

Comment: Hi, there, D Manokhin: Nor can follow neither in such constructions as this: She neither felt ashamed nor flinched away from her gaze.

 But as H.W. Fowler says: any other negative such as “no”, “not”, “never”, should be followed with “OR”.  The negative’s force is carried on.[I couldn’t eat or sleep] not [ I couldn’t eat nor sleep].

So, I think the “nor” in your example should be changed to “or”.

Comment: @Lambie is correct. The use of flinch is wrong here, because the man can flinch his gaze away from her, or he can flinch away from her gaze, be he cannot flinch away from his own gaze. He is not in his own gaze unless he is looking in the mirror.